# Sort df Output by Mount Point

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, filesystems, df

I need to get the output of `df -h` sorted alphabetically by its mount point in the `Mounted on` column.

However, `df -h` currently outputs similar to this:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  228G   14G  203G   7% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  7.9M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdf2        17T   17T  3.3T  56% /mnt/data/drive014
/dev/sdl1        17T   17T   53G 100% /mnt/data/drive006
/dev/sdd1        17T   17T  102G 100% /mnt/data/drive002
/dev/sda1        17T   17T   26G 100% /mnt/data/drive001
```

Is there a command to get it output like below?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  228G   14G  203G   7% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  7.9M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1        17T   17T   26G 100% /mnt/data/drive001
/dev/sdd1        17T   17T  102G 100% /mnt/data/drive002
/dev/sdl1        17T   17T   53G 100% /mnt/data/drive006
/dev/sdf2        17T   17T  3.3T  56% /mnt/data/drive014
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash, you can do this:

```sh
df -h | { read -r line; echo "$line"; sort -k 6,6; }
```

That reads (consumes) and prints the first (header) line, then sort will consume all the rest.

Comment: Why not just `-k6`? What if a mount point contains space(s)?

Comment: if the mount point contains spaces the admin should be arrested

Comment: `LC_ALL=C df -lk --output=target,source,fstype,size,used,avail,pcent | (sed -u 1q; sort -k 1,1)`